# PostgreSQL Optimize data model for deletions (ON CASCADE and denormalization)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I am studying how to optimize a data model on a POSTGRESQL 15 database by adding shortcuts between tables (denormalization).

In a nut shell, I have le following model, which, as you can see consists of three tables. A small one, a medium one in the middle and a very large one.

```
               ,---------------------------------.               
               |SMALL_TABLE                      |               
               |---------------------------------|               
               |description : Contains ~ 100 rows|               
               `---------------------------------'               
                                1                                
                                | 
                                *                               
             ,-------------------------------------.             
             |MEDIUM_TABLE                         |             
             |-------------------------------------|             
             |description : Contains ~ 500 000 rows|             
             `-------------------------------------'   
                                1          
                                |
                                *                                
,---------------------------------------------------------------.
|BIG_TABLE                                                      |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|description : Partitionned table that contains millions of rows|
`---------------------------------------------------------------'
```

I am testing how fast I can delete a row from the SMALL table (and recursively delete rows from MEDIUM_TABLE and BIG_TABLE pointing to the row I deleted).

1. With this model and ON DELETE CASCADE on foreign keys, I get the worst performance (5012.957 ms)
   As you can imagine, the cascade deletion between MEDIUM TABLE and BIG_TABLE takes a lot of time.

Then I tried denormalizing the model as follow

```
               ,---------------------------------.               
               |SMALL_TABLE                      |               
               |---------------------------------|               
               |description : Contains ~ 100 rows|               
               `---------------------------------'               
                         1               1   
                         |               |
                         *               |                        
 ,-------------------------------------. |                       
 |MEDIUM_TABLE                         | |                       
 |-------------------------------------| |                       
 |description : Contains ~ 500 000 rows| |                       
 `-------------------------------------' |                       
                         1               |
                         |               |
                         *               *
,---------------------------------------------------------------.
|BIG_TABLE                                                      |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|description : Partitionned table that contains millions of rows|
`---------------------------------------------------------------'
```

I was worried having ON CASCADE on all constraints would degrade the performances when deleting rows on SMALL_TABLE (since cascade deletions would be checks twice for the BIG_TABLE because of the two foreign keys).

Turns my tests proved me wrong:

2. With cascade deletions on all foreign keys (despite all foreign keys auto deleting triggering): **2051.856 ms (best score)**
   According to the execution plan, the cascade deletion from MEDIUM_TABLE to BIG_TABLE runs super fast (probably thanks to the "shortcut" that is triggered before).
3. Without cascade deletions at all (the result is the sum of all deletions): 4133 ms

Here are the volumes of data I tested with:

- SMALL_TABLE: 20 rows
- MEDIUM_TABLE: 200 000 rows
- LARGE_TABLE: 40 000 000 rows

Since my test consists in deleting a single row from SMALL_TABLE, it triggers 10 000 deletions in MEDIUM_TABLE and 2 000 000 deletions in LARGE_TABLE.

Do these results seem logical to you or is it just "luck"?

Here is a sample of my denormalized test with an explain plan of my results.
As you can see, the foreign keys on SMALL_TABLE are triggered first which seems to prevent fk_medium_table from taking too long.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS large_table;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS medium_table;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS small_table;

create table small_table
(
    uid  smallint generated by default as identity
        constraint pk_small_table
            primary key
);

create table medium_table
(
    uid                 bigint generated by default as identity
        constraint pk_medium_table
            primary key,
    uid_small_table  smallint    not null
        constraint fk_small_table
            references small_table ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX medium_table_uid_small_table_idx ON medium_table USING btree (uid_small_table);

create table large_table
(
    uid                 bigint generated by default as identity
        constraint pk_large_table
            primary key,
    uid_medium_table           bigint                      not null
        constraint fk_medium_table
            references medium_table ON DELETE CASCADE,
    uid_small_table  smallint                    not null
        constraint fk_small_table
            references small_table ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX large_table_uid_medium_table_idx ON large_table USING btree (uid_medium_table);
CREATE INDEX large_table_uid_small_table_idx ON large_table USING btree (uid_small_table);

do
$$
    DECLARE
        nb_small                smallint := 20;
        nb_medium_per_small     smallint := 10000;
        nb_large_per_medium   bigint   := 200;
    BEGIN


        INSERT INTO small_table (uid)
            (SELECT generate_series(1, nb_small));


        INSERT INTO medium_table (uid_small_table)
            (SELECT st.uid
             FROM (SELECT generate_series(1, nb_medium_per_small) as code) sub,
                  small_table st
            );

        INSERT INTO large_table (uid_medium_table, uid_small_table)
            (SELECT mt.uid, mt.uid_small_table
             from medium_table mt,
                  (SELECT generate_series(1, nb_large_per_medium, 1)) sub
             );
    END
$$;

-- +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
-- |QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                      |
-- +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
-- |Delete on small_table  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=0.112..0.112 rows=0 loops=1)                               |
--     |  ->  Index Scan using pk_small_table on small_table  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.073..0.074 rows=1 loops=1)|
--     |        Index Cond: (uid = 1)                                                                                                   |
--     |Planning Time: 0.177 ms                                                                                                         |
--     |Trigger for constraint fk_small_table on small_table: time=36.162 calls=1                                                       |
--     |Trigger for constraint fk_small_table on small_table: time=1230.031 calls=1                                                     |
--     |Trigger for constraint fk_medium_table on medium_table: time=783.771 calls=10000                                                |
--     |Execution Time: 2051.856 ms                                                                                                     |
--     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
explain analyze
    delete from small_table where uid = 1;
```

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for the tables and indexes involved? And the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your delete-statements.

Comment: There's not enough information here to make a meaningful assessment. Are the reported times from a single run for each approach or the mean over serveral runs? How many total rows across the three tables are being deleted? Although the percentage difference in the run times between the approaches appears significant, the absolute difference doesn't seem sufficient to warrant denormalizing the data model.

Comment: Afaict, the names of the foreign key cascade deletion triggers are random, and so is their order, which would mean this is just luck

Comment: Your data models represent totally different constructs.  The first model (without shortcut?) requires rows in `big_table` to have a corresponding entry in `medium_table` to be effected by delete on `small_table` . The second allows 'big_table` to directly relate to `small_table`. This requires `big_table` to have 2 FKs and `on delete cascade` must follow **both** paths; potentially slowing things down. Also requiring additional processing on insert/update to ensure only 1 of the FKs is populated. Again indicating your results are incomplete and just luck, but good or bad?

Comment: I agree foreign are expensive on insertions. 
I don't know if getting rid of them on very large tables is acceptable. 
Sure, I loose data integrity validation, but I can improve performance drastically.

Comment: If you don't know if a data model without foreign keys is acceptable for your application, how should someone else know? We don't know if data integrity is more important than performance, or not. Getting the wrong answer very fast, might not be what you want.

Comment: A circular data model isn't good practice either: https://medium.com/akurey/dont-be-circular-b59c5609d472

Comment: @FrankHeikens, I am not asking you if removing foreign keys is the solution, I am asking if it is acceptable to consider the option ;)

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think my model has circular dependencies since SMALL_TABLE doesn't reference BIG_TABLE (it is the other way around).

Comment: @Belayer I don't see how that model is a "totally different construct". Foreign key constraints are basically transitive, it should not matter (for the data) whether there is an additional direct FK from `big_table` to `small_table` or not.